# Understanding: Tensorflow Batch Norm Corrections in tf.contrib.quantize

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

In the Tensorflow package `tf.contrib.quantize`, there is a module that folds batch norm layers. It has a parameter called `freeze_batch_norm_delay`, which is supposed to freeze the moving mean and variance of the folded batch norm layers.

I am running some network (MobileNet+SSD) and inserted tf.contrib.quantize support. After 30k steps, the batch norms become frozen (freeze_bn_delay=30000). This is what happens to the loss:

[Plot of the loss function, with batch norm freeze occuring at 30k steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmBST.png)

The loss makes a sudden jump when freezing the batch norm layers. I would expect that before and after the freeze should be identical, except that mean and variance won't be updated any longer ("freeze").

Could somebody explain to me what those corrections are?

Here is what the source code states, but it didn't help:

```
Computes batch norm correction params.
Before batch normalization is frozen:
We use batch statistics for batch norm.
  correction_scale = sigma_b/sigma_mv
  correction_recip = 1/correction_scale
  correction_offset = 0
After batch normalization is frozen:
  correction_scale = sigma_b/sigma_mv
  correction_recip = 1
  correction_offset =  gamma*(mu_b/sigma_b-mu_mv/sigma_mv).
Batch norm is frozen if global_step > bn_freeze_delay.

The corrections ensure that:
 a) The weights are quantized after scaling by gamma/sigma_mv. This enables
    smoother training as the scaling on the weights changes slowly, rather than
    jump across mini-batches
 b) Changing the values of the corrections allows for one to switch between
    using batch statistics to using moving mean and average, without requiring
    changes to batch_norm
```

Here is the function definition:
[_ComputeBatchNormCorrections](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize/python/fold_batch_norms.py#L276)

I do not understand why the text above claims that we switch between batch statistics and moving mean and average, when a freeze is supposed to occur. Is that a "freeze"?

I have searched for an answer on the web, however, as this package apparently is in active development, I have not found any explanations.

Comment: The usual cause for this spike is not running batch norm update ops (meaning the "moving" mean and variance aren't updated, and switching to them normalizes with whatever the defaults are; this is a shock compared to the batch statistics used during training). So double check that your `session.run` includes the update ops collection?

Comment: Thanks @AllenLavoie. I will double check that. The model uses slim.batch_norm, which, according to its documentation, adds the update_ops to a collection, so they should be included automatically, unless the collection was modified. I will test if I can see that in the graph displayed with Tensorboard.

Comment: hi, did you fix this issue?